# How to prevent my hair and brreads from growing in to grey?

Tags: hair

I am 24 years old and I am suffering from a hair problem. Like some of my hairs are becoming grey from the root and my beards too are becoming
grey and hair fall problem too.

I have visited a doctor and the doctor has given me two medicines for that:

1. **Vt-Cure 150(intake:saturday and sunday only)**
2. **Trichophyton(intake:monday to friday).**

But still there is no effect on my hair as my hair and beard are still becoming white.

I am doing hair color:**Loreal Paris(ammonia free)** in 1 month atleast or sometimes in 1.5 months.

Is this medicine good for my hair??

So can anybody tell me the solutions for this??

Comment: doctors don't give out medicine lightly (Well, where I live they don't). If they think it works, stick with it. It doesn't always work overnight, you know!

Comment: Welcome to lifehacks! Unfortunately, medical questions such as this are off-topic here.

Comment: @Mooseman:can you please give me any site reference like where i can ask this kinds of question to experts and i can get reply??

Comment: @user3524566 There's a "Health Stack Exchange" coming soon: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health?referrer=UWyA_0J8jPRQmED-qdK94Q2

Comment: @Mooseman:can i ask this kinds of questions there??

Comment: @user3524566 Once the site launches, yes.

Comment: @Mooseman:when is the site launching then and do we have experts here on this website who can give me answer correctly??